# how to convert string to file path(sdcard path)? android

Tags: android, filepath

i parsed my xml file successfully using sax parser.my doubt is how to convert string to file path. i have 3 spinner the 1st spinner show my parent node string value and 2nd spinner show child node name tag value and 3rd spinner show path tag value. this is my xml file link pls see this link = http://paste.org/42924

I hope you are clear now I am trying to convert my path tag string value to sdcard file path. I stored my path tag string value in path_List array list. Now I got all path string value in this array list.  how to convert this sting value to file path? I wish to show images in same screen bottom in grid view format that's all. now I stored the path tag string value in my array list the array list name is path_List. how to convert convert my file path?

this is my source code:

```
public class ParxmlActivity extends Activity {

    private String array_spinner[];
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex;

    ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet= null;


    ArrayList<String> hltag_List=new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Subchild> sltag_List=new ArrayList<Subchild>();

    ArrayList<String> name_List = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    ArrayList<String> path_List =new ArrayList<String>();

    Spinner spinner_hltag,spinner_sltag, spinner_path;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_hltag;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_sltag;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_path;
    int hltagPos = 0;
    int sltagPos = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);

            spinner_hltag= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner_sltag = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner_path =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        try {
            /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
            ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

            /* Parse the xml-data from our file. */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("neevee.xml")));
            /* Parsing has finished. */

            parsedExampleDataSet =myExampleHandler. myParsedExampleDataSet;

            for (int i = 0; i < parsedExampleDataSet.gethltag().size(); i++) {
                Log.v("gethltag SIZE ", ""+parsedExampleDataSet.gethltag().size());
                hltag_List.add(parsedExampleDataSet.getHLTag().get(i));
            }


            sltag_List = parsedExampleDataSet.getSLTag(hltag_List.get(hltagPos));

            for(int i = 0; i < sltag_List.size(); i++) {
                name_List.add(sltag_List.get(i).name);
                path_List.add(sltag_List.get(i).path);
            }

            adapter_hltag = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ParxmlActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hltag_List); 
            spinner_hltag.setAdapter(adapter_hltag);


            adapter_sltag = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ParxmlActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, name_List); 
            spinner_sltag.setAdapter(adapter_sltag); 


            adapter_path = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ParxmlActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, path_List); 
            spinner_path.setAdapter(adapter_path);

        } catch (Exception e) { 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are just parsing string array list only. so it will display just string. if you want you need to create custom array adapter which has an image view to display your image.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I wish to show images in gridview in same screen instead of my third spinner. the third spinner show only path tag string value now, how to convert that string value and shown images in grid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
 sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

//Create a new class called ImageAdapter that extends BaseAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return path_List.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
for (int i=0;i<path_List.size();i++){
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return imageView;
}


    }
```

Comment: error 1: path_List.length cannot be resolved or is not a field  error 2: The method decodeFile(String) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments 
 (ArrayList<String>)

Comment: try this Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get[i]);

Comment: path_List.get cannot be resolved or is not a field error padma sir

Comment: this one really helps you I geuss. if not sent your project to me I will check it.